# Problem uploading large files in aws s3 using aws-sdk in angular

Tags: angular, file, upload

I want to upload large files even files greater than 2 gb of the files that are uploaded on aws s3.

I tried it using aws-sdk  by simple code that uploading the full file reading it from file reader and then uploading it to s3 bucket, i haven't used any multipart or something but while uploading If i check my netword tab  aws s3 is automatically uploading it into chunks and the UI is blocked till the file is uploaded.

But i want that large file uploading should be a background process i knnow about worker in javascript but still how to implement them with aws s3 ?

Even for multipart and progress there is aws-amplify

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.